# How do I rewrite all variables in $_REQUEST?

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering if there is a quick way to loop through `$_REQUEST` and change all the submitted variables by running them through a function.

For example, say I was given `$_REQUEST['a']` whose value was `stuff` and `$_REQUEST['b']` whose value was `more stuff`. I would want to rewrite my entire `$_REQUEST[]` array such that the value of `$_REQUEST['a']` became `myfunction('stuff')` and the value of `$_REQUEST['b']` became `myfunction('more stuff')`. I do **not** know the name of all of each of the elements passed to `$_REQUEST.`

Comment: You could address this with a simple for loop.

Comment: I won't help you until you tell me why you want to do this.  I think your going about this wrong, explain what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `array_walk` function and pass the array. Example would be:

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");

function test_alter(&$item1, $key, $prefix)
{
    $item1 = "$prefix: $item1";
}

function test_print($item2, $key)
{
    echo "$key. $item2<br />\n";
}

echo "Before ...:\n";
array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');

array_walk($fruits, 'test_alter', 'fruit');
echo "... and after:\n";

array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');
?>
```

The same way, for your problem, you can do this:

```
function stuff() {
   ///
}
```

And now walk your `$_REQUEST` through the function this way:

```
array_walk($_REQUEST, 'stuff', 'fruit');
```

Comment: When PHP has a built-in function, why not use that! :P

Comment: It's hard to keep track of all the PHP built in functions, there's so many and all in different naming conventions :P

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I do not feel good modifying the *special* `$_REQUEST` array, so I would create another array with modified values - *just in case*:

```
$requestProcessed = array_map('myfunction', $_REQUEST);
```

This way, you get modified values *and* still have access to original values (if you happen to need them).

If it's ok for you to modify the `$_REQUEST` array itself, then `array_walk` is better (as suggested by Praveen Kumar).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you're doing seems like bad news as REQUEST stores all kinds of stuff such as $_COOKIES, $_POST and $_GET variables and whatnot, but if you really want to do that, then you could do it like this:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $val) {
    $_REQUEST[$key] = myFunction($val);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `$_REQUEST` doesn't store anything like SESSION, only user submitted stuff like `$_COOKIE` and `$_POST`.

Comment: I guess it includes even `$_GET`

Comment: yes you're correct, I always get confused by $_REQUEST holding cookies instead of session, it is still very volatile, I will correct the answer.